# Current URL & link matching - with div class checking

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.location

Is there a way to test if your current URL location matches with a link on your page, but also checking that the matching link has a particular div class?

e.g.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){    

// find a-href on page with matching current location URL
jQuery("*").find("a[href='"+window.location.href+"']").each(function(){

    // if matching a-href contains class .aaa
    // then BBB action

    // else if matching a-href contains class .bbb
    // then CCC action

})});
```

Comment: use hasClass('aaa').

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){    

    // find a-href on page with matching current location URL
    jQuery("a[href='"+window.location.href+"']").each(function(){

        if ($(this).hasClass('aaa')) {
            // BBB
        }

        if ($(this).hasClass('bbb')) {
            // CCC
        }
    });

});
```

Edits to your code: Removed the unnecessary `jQuery("*")` coupled with `find`, and removed `$` as an argument. (at the suggestion of comments)

Comment: Isn't using `*` expensive? You can directly use the selector `a[href='"+window.location.href+"']` without using `.find()` :)

Comment: @Terry hahah true, the original jquery was pretty brutal, i'll edit :p

Comment: Why are you passing `$` to the function? It's unnecessary in this case.  You are passing jquery inside a jquery function which is redundant.

Comment: @GaryStorey didnt catch that, fixed